How to get row number for jobid via SQL?
I am trying to extract jobids from data view bases on the emailname.
How can I get the row number if I am getting back multiple jobids?
I tried using ROW_NUMBER() but getting a static value of "1" for all rows.
Here is my query:
SELECT 
j.*,
Row_Number() OVER (Partition by j.jobid ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC) as rowNumber
FROM _Job j 
WHERE j.JobID IN
(
 SELECT TOP 5 JobID
 FROM _Job WITH (NOLOCK) 
 WHERE EmailName like 'TEST_EMAIL_NAME%'
 AND SuppressTracking = 'False' 
 AND category = 'my tracking' 
 AND cast (CreatedDate as date) > CAST (getdate() - 40 as date)
 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
)


The typical pattern to use this is for deduplication;
Here the row_number() function goes into the subselect.
in the code below, subselect has alias: a
SELECT
a.JobID
FROM (
  SELECT 
  TOP 5 JobID
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(j.jobid ORDER BY j.CreatedDate ASC) AS Row_Number   
  FROM _Job j
  WITH (NOLOCK) 
  WHERE j.EmailName like 'TEST_EMAIL_NAME%' 
  AND j.SuppressTracking = 'False' 
  AND j.category = 'my tracking' 
  AND cast (j.CreatedDate as date) > CAST (getdate() - 40 as date)
) a
WHERE a.Row_Number = 1

...but you don't seem to want to deduplicate, so just take the rowNumber into the output and omit the WHERE.
SELECT 
a.JobID
,a.Row_Number as rowNumber
FROM (
  SELECT 
  TOP 5 JobID
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(j.jobid ORDER BY j.CreatedDate ASC) AS Row_Number   
  FROM _Job j 
  WITH (NOLOCK) 
  WHERE j.EmailName like 'TEST_EMAIL_NAME%' 
  AND j.SuppressTracking = 'False' 
  AND j.category = 'my tracking' 
  AND cast (j.CreatedDate as date) > CAST (getdate() - 40 as date)
) a

-> should give you
JobID,rowNumber
job11111,1
job11111,2
job22222,1
job22222,2
job22222,3

